# How to ensure existence of all language keys in a property file

Tags: jsp, maven, internationalization, thymeleaf

I have diffenrent language keys in JSP or Thymeleaf templates.

It is important, that at least the default property file (english language) has a tuple for all those keys. 
Is there a Maven plugin or some thing else to ensure, that all used keys can be found in the property file?

BR
Christian

Comment: The question is what you mean by `used keys` from where do you know which keys are used?

Comment: When a key is placed in a jsp template, it is likely to be used bei the application. So the maven plugin would have to parse the jsp files, for example.

Comment: See my answer about custom rule there you have to implement the parsing of jsp file...

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a job for the [maven-enforcer-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/maven-enforcer-plugin/) where you can implement an [appropriate custom rule](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-api/writing-a-custom-rule.html) where you can implement such checks.